# How Does Scoping Work for Task.Factory.Startnew?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, scope

I have a Silverlight website which is calling a WCF service so that it can do some server-side loading. The WCF call is asynchronous, since it's Silverlight-ready, so on it's completion, I am reading data from the `CompletedEventArgs` to load the class. However, I am uncertain of how the scoping works. Is `data` the same in scope of the new task as it is outside? It doesn't seem to ever get set to `true`. I know that the service is working, because the async call is happening, <s>however I cannot debug the completion event triggering since I can't attach a debugger to the "ASP.net-hosted-Silverlight" (is there a way to get around this? I'd love to be able to debug the Silverlight when its .aspx is hosted...).</s> I figured this out with [this link.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/fd874e32-2e9d-47a8-89fa-b514e3ed0509/attaching-to-silverlight-process-separately) I am currently testing my project, but I am still curious as to how this scoping works.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I realize this may be a terrible way to structure this functionality, and I am up for alternative suggestions :)

```
// Objects constructor calls async WCF task, upon completion of which (grammar?)
//    sets IsComplete to true
Foo data = new Foo(param);

Task waitForComplete = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!data.IsComplete)
        {
            // Wait 1 second, then poll again
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
        }
    });

Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { waitForComplete });

// Now that the task has completed, we can access its data
bar.AddRange(data.GetFoo());
```

Comment: You could just call `Wait` on the task, or just spin on the initial thread. Its not clear what using a `Task` does for you here.

Comment: -.- You make a good point. It does absolutely nothing for me here :) It's been one of those Mondays... I will just have the `while` loop

Comment: @ADam But I think the problem is that you're blocking the main thread, which is probably preventing the Foo task from completing and setting IsComplete...

Comment: Then Reed's answer explains a better pattern for you to use in this situation. Is there an event raised when `IsComplete` is set?

Comment: Only what happens on async WCF completed callbacks, which isn't the problem. See my comment on Reed's answer. Mike's suggestion fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you're blocking the main thread by the call to `Task.WaitAll`.  It's likely that the `Foo` class is trying to post a callback onto that thread, which will never succeed.  This would explain why you never actually "finish" the task.

In general, a better approach to this would be to avoid the polling if possible (one option, for example, is to expose the `Task`/`Task<T>` to the caller, so you can attach a continuation there).  However, if you can't change the implementation of `Foo`, you could switch this to handle setting the data as a continuation instead of blocking:

```
// Don't block
// Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { waitForComplete });

// Instead, schedule a continuation that runs when the task is done...
waitForComplete.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // Now that the task has completed, we can access its data
    bar.AddRange(data.GetFoo());
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion in general. Though I was blocking a separate thread in my above example, I definitely should be doing this by default. So even if we return from scope, the objects will be available to the `ContinueWith` expression after the task is complete?

Comment: @Adam Yes - you can always close over other variables in a lambda.  Scope isn't the issue in your original...

Comment: By "post a callback" do you mean the async task completion? Because I know that isn't the issue -- I have one preceding async call, the completed callback of which *is* getting called, because it triggers a second async call (that I know to be firing).

Comment: @Adam If it's using `await`, then yes, that'll cause the problem (provided it's not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`)

Comment: I am still marking this as correct, since your comments answer my question about scoping, and it is all around a solid answer. However, (for future readers) note that this isn't an issue with async WFC service calls.